# How to fetch data according to their category with firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm creating a app in which a admin add Lab Services from Admin Panel according to their categories as same as in Firebase Database (Screenshot that i have provided), and this is working well but at the user end (Client end) i'm trying to fetch these services by selecting their categories, For example at the user end first i want user will select the service's category and by matching the category name all the services that are available in that category will shows to the user. I'm Trying to fetch That Category Blood and Bone in a Spinner, is it possible to fetch Blood and Bone in a spinner if not then in which way user will select service according to category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match category and fetch child like below:

In **Kotlin**:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.orderByKey().equalTo("LAB_SERVICE").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

    }

    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val blood = dataSnapshot.child("LAB_SERVICE").child("Blood").getValue(Blood::class.java)
        val bone = dataSnapshot.child("LAB_SERVICE").child("Bone").getValue(Bone::class.java)
    }

})
```

In **Java**:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().orderByKey().equalTo("LAB_SERVICE").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Blood blood = dataSnapshot.child("LAB_SERVICE").child("Blood").getValue(Blood.class);
        Bone bone = dataSnapshot.child("LAB_SERVICE").child("Bone").getValue(Blood.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get complete data by the node name.

1. get the data path reference.
2. fetch all data for that node.

try following code

```
   myRef = mainDataBaseRef.child("Lab_SERVICE")
    MyDatabaseReference.myRef
        .addValueEventListener(object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if(p0.value!=null) {
                    val map: HashMap<String, Any> = p0.value as HashMap<String, Any>

                    for (entry in map.entries) {
                        val key = entry.key
                        val tab: HashMap<String, String> = entry.value as HashMap<String, String>

                        for (tab in tab.entries) {
                            val key = tab.key
                            val data = tab.value as String

                            list.add(data)
                        }
                    }

                    /*here you can use list */
                }
            }

        })
```

Comment: yes you are right but i thing you are not getting my point, i want whenever Admin add a service with their category name it will fetched in spinner, because in your code i have to specify all the categories name to fetch

Comment: you can modify your mainDataBaseRef as per your requirements, if you used myRef = mainDataBaseRef.child("Lab_SERVICE") , you can get your categories list.
I just edit my answer, you can try latest one